# Change smb://new-host-4.workgroup to smb://whatiwant.workgroup

Tags: network, macos, file-sharing

For some reason macOS won't obey my preferences for host name. If I set my computer name to `whatiwant`, then change the NETBIOS name to `whatiwant` and workgroup name to `workgroup` under WINS configuration in Network settings, when I go to Sharing in System Preferences, I see:

> Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes, at smb://new-host-4.workgroup.

I don't know where else I need to change the host name to stop making it use `new-host-4`.

I tried rebooting, but that didn't fix the problem.

This is a MacBook Pro, connecting to a home network and being assigned an IP address via DHCP on a typical broadband router. Here's the DHCP config. Perhaps the issue is related to the highlighted checkbox.

I tried renewing my DHCP lease but that didn't change the SMB hostname.

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: @Harv I did, but that didn't work. Updated the question.

Comment: To rephrase the question - are you assigning hostnames from DHCP server?

Comment: @Allan, I think that might be the issue. This is checked by default, but since I am setting a hostname in macOS, I don't understand why it's assigning its own. Renewing the lease did not solve this problem.

Comment: In your DHCP, delete the lease, and then restart your Mac.  This will force your Mac to get a new IP and name.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the *local* hostname setting in Sharing preferences? It's found by clicking the **Edit...** button in Sharing preferences.

[image: Local hostname setting]

If that doesn't work, check that the *DHCP Client ID* isn't set. Some DHCP servers will use it to assign a hostname.

You can find it from the **Advanced** section of **Network Preferences**, under the TCP/IP section. Make sure that you have the proper network interface you use selected when you click the **Advanced** button.
[image]